# Get result back from async method in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How get result back from async method ?

```
    async Task<string> Get(string Url)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10485760;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Url);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

call the method

```
var a = Get(address).Result;
Outbox.Text = a;
```

when try to get result, in output winodow i got
"The thread 0xdf4 has exited with code 0 (0x0)"

and nothing happend

but i can get result by this way

```
    async Task Get(string Url)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10485760;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Url);
        Outbox.Text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

and call the method by this way

```
var a = Get(address);
```

i try this code on windows phone 8.1.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, when calling an async method, you're supposed to await it:

```
var a = await Get(address);
Outbox.Text = a;
```

Calling `.Result` is technically valid, but you're freezing the calling thread, which may sometimes result in a deadlock (like in your sample).

Comment: i try this before, the 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

Comment: Which simply means that you need to add the `async` keyword on your method signature. For instance if you have `public void Button_Click(...)`, change it to `public async void Button_Click(...)`